# How to add a listener to the custom control?

Tags: java, swt

I want to add a Selection Listener to my custom control which contains few buttons so that whenever a button is clicked a specific function should be performed by the control. The problem is: I want to add the listener to the control itself and not individually to each of its child buttons. What should I do?

Comment: if your control is a panel or frame itself, the listener could be added to it.

Comment: @Paniz I am using SWT, so basically my custom control is a Composite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the article [Creating Your Own Widgets using SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm):

> SWT Event Mechanism
>
> SWT provides a low-level listener mechanism as well as the usual Java ‘typed’ listeners. Every SWT widget understands addListener(int eventType, Listener listener) and notifyListeners(int eventType, Event event). The eventType constants are defined in class SWT. When an event occurs, the widget creates an SWT Event object containing the appropriate type constant. The notifyListeners method calls handleEvent(Event event) for the Listener. If you need to reuse an existing SWT event, you would typically use this mechanism.
>
> For example, if your widget implements a selection event, you could implement your ‘typed’ add and remove methods as follows:
>
> ```
> public void addSelectionListener(SelectionListener listener) {
>     addListener(SWT.Selection, new TypedListener(listener));
> }
>
> public void removeSelectionListener(SelectionListener listener) {
>     removeListener(SWT.Selection, listener);
> }
> ```
>
> When the ‘selection event’ occurs in your widget (say, when child1 is selected), you notify the application’s selection listeners using notifyListeners.
>
> ```
> child1.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
>     public void handleEvent(Event e) {
>         notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, new Event());
>     }
> });
> ```
>
> Note that when we add the listener we first wrap it in a TypedListener. This is because TypedListener’s handleEvent(Event event) method creates the appropriate TypedEvent subclass based on the type in the Event, and then calls the appropriate method for the typed event. In this way, applications can add Java typed listeners to widgets, but widget implementations can use the more efficient low-level listener mechanism. Make sure that your widget implementation provides a typed listener API, however. Applications should not be calling low-level listener methods. The typed listener methods prevent accidental programming errors such as assuming that all widgets can handle all types of event, or that all fields in the Event class are valid for all events.